# Spreadsheet GUI - Python 3.4

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, tkinter, spreadsheet

I would like the user to copy data from Excel and paste it in the spreadsheet like GUI and then press OK. This data (three columns +100/1000 rows) will be stored in an array for subsequent calculations further on in the program.

I would prefer to use tkinter since it's already included in my Python installation and others like wxPython are not supported by Python 3.4.

I already have the following but there are some issues:
1. I cannot paste data into the table.
2. The number of rows is fixed. So what to do if my data is bigger than the table?

```
class SimpleTableInput(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self._entry = {}
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns


    # create the table of widgets
    for row in range(self.rows):
        for column in range(self.columns):
            index = (row, column)
            e = tk.Entry(self)
            e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
            self._entry[index] = e
    # adjust column weights so they all expand equally
    for column in range(self.columns):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
    # designate a final, empty row to fill up any extra space
    self.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)

def get(self):
    '''Return a list of lists, containing the data in the table'''
    result = []
    for row in range(self.rows):
        current_row = []
        for column in range(self.columns):
            index = (row, column)
            current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
        result.append(current_row)
    return result

class Example(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 20, 3)
    self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()>
```

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Please try to solve the problem yourself, and then come back to stackoverflow with _specfic_ questions.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to spend months writing your own code to "translate" the excel sheet into something python can use I suggest you take a look at: http://www.python-excel.org/

---

Depending on the type of file (.xls, .xlsx) you will need to use specific modules to read/write. Further information can be found in the library documentation.

Here's simple program that prints to screen a .xls file, this should get you started.

```
import xlrd
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile

data = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

book = xlrd.open_workbook(data) #open our xls file
sheet = book.sheets()[0] #book.sheets() returns a list of objects alternatively...
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("qqqq") #we can pull by name
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) #or by the index it has in excel's sheet collection

r = sheet.row(0) #returns all the CELLS of row 0,
c = sheet.col_values(0) #returns all the VALUES of row 0,

datastore = [] #make a data store

for i in xrange(sheet.nrows):
    datastore.append(sheet.row_values(i)) #drop all the values in the rows into datastore
print (datastore)
```

Code example taken from [here](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/)

Comment: I get " name 'tkFileDialog' is not defined "

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you need to import tkFileDialog, not tkinter. The program should work on python 2.7, python 3.0 uses different syntax for the tkinter program, but the basic idea is the same.